# What does 'const gchar *' mean, and does that memory need to be freed after use?

Tags: c, string, pointers, gtk, constants

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{

const gchar *wew = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(gtkentrywidget));

return 0;
}
```

`gtk_entry_get_text()` returns a `const gchar*`, so does `wew` need to be deallocated or not, and why?

Comment: I don't normally criticize grammar, spelling, punctuation, or capitalization, especially since there are many non-native English speakers on the site, but I cannot understand what you mean. Are you asking just about allocation and deallocation, or do you need clarification on what `const` is as well? Please use proper English sentence structure in your questions.

Comment: its all about allocating and deallocating, if you mind please answer the question that i've asked to @corynelson instead of thinkin what im tryin to accomplish on the first question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gtk_entry_get_text` returns a `const gchar*` instead of a `gchar*` to prevent you from trying to free the memory. The documentation of the function even tells you so. Of course if you cast the returned value to `gchar*`, you're able to free it, but that's just because the C language doesn't prevent you from doing silly things.

For exemple, as that memory chunk is internally used by your GtkEntry, if you free that memory chunk, and later call `gtk_entry_set_text`, your program  will crash. This is because the memory where it tries to write is unallocated...

Answer (score 4):

A `gchar` is just a typedef for the C type `char`.  You **must not** deallocate this specific pointer.  Per the [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-get-text):

> Returns : a pointer to the contents of the widget as a string. This string points to internally allocated storage in the widget and must not be freed, modified or stored.

Comment: well i do -> 
`gchar *wew = (gchar*)gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(gtkentrywidget));
g_free(wew);`
and its all fine, why these could be performed ?

Comment: If you are calling g_free then that is undefined behavior (UB). Sure it may "seem" to work, but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: why i must not do it when it seems to work ?, what is undefined behavior (UB) mean ?

Comment: The documentation tells you not to.  It's merely a coincidence that what you're doing appears to work.  Don't do it!

Comment: You should never ever free anything that is given to you marked as a const. The object itself is usually under the control of some other library that will free it much later.  Freeing a const is undefined.